# Yammer statistics through APIs

Tags: api, rest, statistics, yammer

We have a CMS-solution, where Yammer is integrated using the "Embedded Feed". Next to most of the pages in the solution, there is a Yammer part for comments and liking.

Now we would like to increase the functionality with the following:

1. A list of the most liked pages
2. A list of the most commented pages
3. How many people liked the current page
4. How many people commented current page

Anyone have experience with this? Ie, to collect already summarized data, or retrieve data and summarize yourself in the solution? And especially dealt with [rate limits](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/rest-api-rate-limits#rate-limits) and worked with some form of caching?

Answer (score 0):

The Yammer APIs are very limited in functionality, and will not support what you are trying to do.

Even without the throttling, getting the most liked and most-commented pages are going to be flat-out impossible. There's no way to query for most-liked or most-commented Open Graph objects. (Unless I am mistaken)

To get the total likes and comments on a given page, ignoring the throttling issues, here's what you could do:

Pages are represented as Open Graph objects in Yammer. Getting the likes and comments is a 2-step process. First, you need to grab the Open Graph ID of a given URL, then fetch the messages related to that OG object. But, again, you'll only get the first twenty.

To grab the OG object:

```
yam.platform.request({
    url: "open_graph_objects?url=" + url.toLowerCase(),
    method: "GET",
    data: {},
    success: function (OGObj) {
        //your id is in the OGObj.id
    }
});
```

then, to get the messages:

```
yam.platform.request({
    url: "messages/open_graph_objects/" + OG_id + ".json",
    method: "GET",
    data: {},
    success: function (msg) {
        //parse out this object for the messages, which 
        // contain like and comments counts
    }
});
```

**Now, there is a Yammer "Like" button that allows you to directly "Like" Yammer Oopen Graph objects, but incredibly there is no way to actually retreive those Likes. You can only get likes on messages related to those URLs.